# "We strongly advise you to enjoy this book before turning to the Introduction"

Tags: expressions

This was part of *General Introduction* (it's right before the Introduction) of some Wordsworth Classics series,

> We strongly advise you to enjoy this book before turning to the
>   Introduction.

What does that mean? I'm little confused.

1. Since the Introduction is before the actual text, how should I "enjoy" the book? Maybe I didn't get it.
2. Enjoyment is a rather personal feeling: how could I be *advised to enjoy* the book?

Comment: No-one seems to have mentioned (maybe it's obvious) but they are warning you that reading the Introduction first might spoil your experience of the book in itself, e.g. by discussing points about the story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People sometimes use "enjoy' as an imperative (command) meaning to use or consume the thing. "Enjoy your lunch" means "go ahead and eat". "Enjoy the movie" means "you may now go in the theater and watch the movie". Etc. (It's always seemed a little presumptuous to me. How do you know that I will enjoy it? Maybe I will do it, but hate every minute of it.)

In this case, "enjoy the book" simply means to read the book. So they are saying that you should read the main text of the book before you read the introduction.

Comment: Just don't read the Introduction and the main text at the same time. Especially if you're enjoying your lunch too.

Comment: Shouldn't "introductions" like that be called "afterwords"? They are certainly **not** intended to introduce you to the book.

Comment: Is it still presumptuous if the dictionary recongizes this as a valid meaning/use of the word? **enjoy**: [spoken] *used for saying that you hope someone enjoys something that they are about to do* (from [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/enjoy)).

Comment: @J.R.; It certainly is. A waiter who says *Enjoy* as whe serves your meal is not *ipso facto* ungrammatical; but he probably is presumptuous (since whether you enjoy it depends on the cook), just as he may be smarmy, unctuous and badly-dressed.

Comment: @TimLymington: I don't see anything inherently wrong with a waiter saying *"Enjoy your meal"*. I understand it not as a "presumptuous command", but rather as *"On behalf of all the people working in this establishment, may I just say we all hope you will enjoy your meal"*. Presumably in your case if he'd come out with the full form you'd probably reply *"No, you may not!"*.

Comment: @TimLymington: I always respond, "I will.... if it's good. Enjoy your work."

Comment: If someone says "Do X", I normally take this as a command that I am expected or required to do X, not as a statement of hope that I will want to do X. Like if the boss says, "Come to the staff meeting at 9:00", I take that as a command, not as "I hope that you will want to come, etc". Even if it's for my own good and the person has no power to compel me, like when the doctor says, "Take two of these pills every days", the person is saying that this is what you ought to do. So "Enjoy your meal" seems presumptuous to me. The waiter is assuming that the meal is, in fact, enjoyable. ...

Comment: ... Of course I'm not going to jump up and scream obscenities at him. On the list of things in life that annoy me, this ranks somewhat below violence in the Middle East and having to pay taxes.

Comment: Another stray thought: if you read the book but don't enjoy it, doesn't that mean the introduction-writer is advising you not to read the introduction at all?

Comment: @TimLymington You have to keep re-reading the book until you enjoy it. Then you're allowed to read the introduction.

Comment: @TimLymington: I interpret "enjoy" as I would "be well": a wish that things go well for you, rather than a prediction of the future or a command, even if they are grammatical imperatives.

Comment: @J.R. Very late follow-up comment: Just because a use of a word is found in the dictionary and is grammatically correct doesn't make it not-presumptuous for someone to say it. If someone says, "You should do everything I say because I am a genius and you are a moron", that sentence is completely grammatically correct and every word is used with it's proper definition, but I'd still think it a rather presumptuous thing to say. :-)